# Looping through CSV files, performing a function, and concatenating DataFrame objects

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, csv

I am attempting to loop through multiple CSVs, find the mean of multiple variable columns (6 to be specific) within the CSV, which in turn will output a single row of results (6,1) in dimensions, and append that to a dataframe object, for all .csv files in the folder.

I am quite new to programming, and the first code section below does not give the desired output.

My attempted code is as such:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

appended_data = []

folder= r"C:\Users\A\Desktop\Analysis\Field result\Height"

for file in Path(folder).glob('*.csv'):
    
    #Print filename to see which file is being processed
    #will use filenames later to add a column to appended_data to use as date-time
    print(os.path.basename(file))
    
    #Read csv
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    
    #Averaging all variables of interest; mean, min, max, median etc.
    averages = df[df.columns[3:9]].mean()
             
    #Transpose to store as row
    Averages_Data = averages_pd.T
    
    # store DataFrame in list
    appended_data.append(Averages_Data)
    
#see pd.concat documentation for more info
appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)

print(appended_data)
```

I am able to do it manually for the first two .csvs with the code below:

```
height = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\A\Desktop\Analysis\Field result\Height\height1.csv")
height.head()
height.info()
averages = height[height.columns[3:9]].mean()
print(averages)
Averages_Data = averages_pd.T
height2 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Al\Desktop\Analysis\Field result\Height\height2.csv")
averages2 = height2[height2.columns[3:9]].mean()
print(averages2)
Averages2 = averages2_pd.T
Averages2
Averages_Data
x = pd.concat([Averages_Data, Averages2])
```

and this gives the results I am looking for, but I can't seem to be able to generalise it, doing it manually will take too long. How would I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "I can't seem to be able to generalise it"?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity I mean to say I dont know how I would do the second part of the code  recursively, so I do not have to run the function on every database, and concatenate it manually

Comment: don't you already have that from the top code snippet though? not sure I follow

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Unfortunately not, the output just prints the result of the first .mean() function result for the first dataset n times, for the n number of datasets i'm trying to loop over

Comment: you don't print any mean function in that code snippet though. Can you paste your full code please?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity that is the full code, in the first code block, at the end of 'averages = df[df.columns[3:9]].mean()'  there is a mean function attached

Comment: yes but there's no print there within the loop, there's no way the code you've written would " just prints the result of the first .mean() function result for the first dataset n times"

Comment: besides, `averages_pd` would be undefined

Comment: @ignoring_gravity That's not true though? It appends the result of the .mean() function to the appended_data object, and that prints at the end; it prints through the .append into the list? Its definitely defined, its just converting the series produced from the .mean() line to a dataframe

Comment: No, `averages_pd` comes out of the blue - the code wouldn't run? Also: `height[height.columns[3:9]].mean()` etc. is a Series, so transposing doesn't do anything?

Comment: @Timus The code does run, when I print the Averages_Data variable associated with it, it outputs a DataFrame (transposed) with the associated means, the averages_pd converts the series to a DataFrame

Comment: Then there's something missing in your question: I literally copied your code, and ran it against some sample files (both parts seperately). Both times I got - _as expected_ - a `NameError`. Look at the question and try to identify the point where `averages_pd` comes into existence.

Comment: @Timus I see, at some point I must have run it as Averages_Data = pd.DataFrame(averages) which would probably output the same thing, I have been trying for a long time and renamed the variables a lot so its entirely possible. Do you have any suggestions as to how to remedy the code above or how I could do the second segment in a for loop/recursively?

Comment: @Timus the issue I have come across is that I would have to do something on the lines of concatenating to a dataframe, but then the result of the concatenation becomes a new dataframe object itself, is there a way to keep it static and just append to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work:

```
from pathlib import Path

folder = r"C:\Users\A\Desktop\Analysis\Field result\Height"
dfs = []
for file in Path(folder).glob("*.csv"):
    print(file.name)
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(file).iloc[:, 3:9].mean().to_frame().T)
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

When I run it, with accordingly adjusted `folder`, for the following 5 sample files

```
from pathlib import Path
from random import randint

folder = "Test"
base = Path(folder)
base.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
cols_str = ",".join(f"col{i}" for i in range(10))
for n in range(1, 6):
    (base / f"file{n}.csv").write_text(
        cols_str + "\n"
        + ",".join(str(randint(1, 100)) for _ in range(10)) + "\n"
        + ",".join(str(randint(1, 100)) for _ in range(10))
    )
```

which essentially look like

```
col0,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9
55,60,77,32,89,49,71,7,60,52
10,40,66,96,45,11,53,36,40,28
```

I get the following `df`:

```
   col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8
0  54.0  61.5  99.5  61.5  34.5  34.5
1  26.5  72.0  65.0  93.0  56.0  73.5
2  53.5  79.0  55.0  68.0  32.5  46.0
3  66.5  44.0  38.5  65.5  16.0  36.5
4  21.0  73.0  54.5  48.5  73.0  45.5
```

Comment: It's worked perfectly, thank you I appreciate it, sorry for the ambiguity on my part I am still quite new to programming. I was just curious if you had any tips for learning purposes, where I went wrong in the code above or how I could've improved it for example?

Comment: @lambda Thanks for the feedback! Hard to say where exactly you went wrong. Imho you pretty much had most of it already together. Sometimes minor mistakes can make the coding life a misery :(( I'd say that studying the ins and outs of how to combine dataframes/series is always very worth the time. There's a lot you will miss at first ...